# override django-allauth custom create user

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I'm using **allauth** for social authentication with custom user model where i don't have **username** field and the **email** field is also not required.(as I'm using **phone** as username).

process goes fine till allauth want to **create the user** here i face `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: user_user.phone` so trying to override the default **allauth create user** method.

I have no idea here all i know is

```
from allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter

class MyAccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):
   # sticks here
```

any idea ? :(

Answer (score 1):

you can override the `DefaultSocialAccountAdapter` here is a quick code for that:

```
from allauth.socialaccount.adapter import DefaultSocialAccountAdapter
from .models import User
from allauth.socialaccount.models import SocialAccount

class UserAccountAdapter(DefaultSocialAccountAdapter):

    def save_user(self, request, user, form, commit=True):
        user.user.tenant = request.tenant
        user = super(UserAccountAdapter, self).save_user(request, user, form)
        user.save()
        social_account = SocialAccount.objects.filter(user=user).first()
        platform_user = User.objects.filter(email = user.email,tenant = request.tenant ).first()
        platform_user.first_name = social_account.extra_data['properties']['nickname'] 
        platform_user.user_image = social_account.extra_data['properties']['profile_image'] 
        platform_user.save()
```

Don't forget to include
`SOCIALACCOUNT_ADAPTER ='accounts.social_auth.UserAccountAdapter'` in your `settings.py`.
Hope it'll help!